# Check if a string is present is two other strings

Tags: python

I would like to check if a short string is present in two longer strings. In psuedocode something like this:

```
'XXX' in (mat_1['name'] & mat_2['name'])
```

On the basis that I get:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'unicode' and 'unicode'
```

I'm clearly barking up the wrong tree for now.

Ben

Comment: use `and` instead of `&` in python for boolean operations. but in your case you mean probably: `('XXX' in mat_1['name']) and ('XXX' in mat_2['name'])`.

Comment: Even `and` should not be used like that . it should be - `('XXX' in mat_1['name']) and ('XXX' in mat_2['name'])`

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? If the string is present in either of the longer strings, or in both of them? Give an example.

Comment: Your pseudocode does not clearly explain what you want to do. What is `(mat_1['name'] & mat_2['name'])` supposed to mean?

Comment: @AnandSKumar, for which input 'XXX' in (mat_1['name'] and mat_2['name']) will not work properly?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque It would not satisfy the requirement, `'XXX' in (<sonmething>,<somethingelse>)` , checks if `XXX` is equal to something or something else, not substring of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [all()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function:

```
to_check = [mat_1['name'], mat_2['name']]
if all('XXX' in s for s in to_check):
    pass  # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code must be,

```
if 'XXX' in mat_1['name'] and 'XXX' in mat_2['name']:
```

or

```
if all('XXX' in i for i in (mat_1['name'] , mat_2['name'] )):
```